# SetWindowPos moves window to different position every time

Tags: c#, winapi, user32

I have a Windows application (which I am writing in C#) that starts with a maximized window without borders.

When the user clicks on a button in the application, I want to restore the window (that is, remove the maximized state), resize it to a certain size and move it to the bottom-right corner of the screen.

My problem is that the call to `SetWindowPos()`, while resizing the window correctly, does not always place it in the bottom-right corner of the screen. Sometimes it does, yet some other times the window is placed elsewhere on the screen (almost as if it were "jumping" around, for a reason which I ignore).

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code. Note that I pass -1 as second parameter to SetWindowPos because I want my window to be on top of every other window.

```
public void MoveAppWindowToBottomRight()
{
    Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

    IntPtr handler = process.MainWindowHandle;

    ShowWindow(handler, 9); // SW_RESTORE = 9
    int x = (int)(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - 380);
    int y = (int)(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 250);

    NativePoint point = new NativePoint { x = x, y = y };

    ClientToScreen(handler, ref point);
    SetWindowPos(handler, -1, point.x, point.y, 380, 250, 0);            
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NativePoint
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

Comment: [SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenwidth.aspx) and [SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenheight.aspx) do not account for the space occupied by the task bar. This is unrelated to the issue of this question. It is another bug you need to address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove these lines:

```
NativePoint point = new NativePoint { x = x, y = y };

ClientToScreen(handler, ref point);
```

And change your call to:

```
SetWindowPos(handler, -1, x, y, 380, 250, 0);
```

Calling `ClientToScreen()` makes no sense as the coordinates you have are already screen coordinates.

Your window gets different positions every time because when you call `ClientToScreen()` it will create new coordinates based *on the window's current position*. This means every time the function is called the coordinates will be different.

---

Also, if you want to take the taskbar size into account you should utilize the [**`Screen.WorkingArea` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreen***`:

```
int x = (int)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 380);
int y = (int)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 250);
```

Comment: Credit to IInspectable for pointing out the thing about the taskbar.

Comment: Thank you @visual-vincent, I didn't know SetWindowPos creates new coordinates based on a relative position. I found out that the call I need is `MoveWindow`, which, for top-level windows, calculates new coordinates relative to the upper-left corner of the screen.

Comment: @AlbertoVenturini : Nonononono, it's `ClientToScreen()` that creates new coordinates relative to the current position. As I said, that's the call you should remove, sorry for being unclear. You may still use `SetWindowPos()`.

Comment: @AlbertoVenturini : The upper-left corner of the screen based coordinates that you mention are precisely what's so called _screen coordinates_.